# Problem with inserting unique value into SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

My code doesn't catch the exception when I try to add the same user to the database and I don't really know how to change it.

```
try
{
    SqlConnection.Open();
    string sqlZapytanie = "INSERT INTO Host Values('" + host.Name + "','" +
         host.Surname + "'," + host.PESEL + ",'" + host.City + "','" + host.Street + "', '" + host.House_number + "','" + host.Apartament_number + "','" + host.e_mail + "'," + host.Phone_number + ",'"+host.Login+"')";

    try
    {
        SqlCommand.Connection = SqlConnection;
        SqlCommand.CommandText = sqlZapytanie;
        SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(SqlException sqlex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sqlex.Message, "Zduplikowany użytkownik.", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

Comment: **SQL Injection Warning:** Parametrize your quey.

Comment: Your code is SQL injection vulnerable.

Comment: Do you have an unique index in that table?

Comment: yes, there is a unique value called "login".

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62117069/edit) your question and include the table DDL. and any indexes on it.

Comment: Considering the error message's language, is `varchar` also the right choice of data type for your highly insecure code here?

Comment: Learn to debug your code. When you run the code in the debugger, which statement throws an exception and what is the type of that exception? For others to help you, that information is needed; otherwise this becomes a big guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the error to be returned is not type SqlException  but type Exception.

Comment: Very unlikely. While SqlCommand does throw a wide range of exceptions, none of them is exception: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery | And you really should not be catching exception for anything but "logging and throw back on": https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/